# Static Pages in Yii Problem

Tags: yii

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<view>' => array('site/page/view/'),
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        //'index' => array('site/index'),
    ),
),
```

I currently have that in my main.php file.

The problem I have is that when I view /index.php/index I have shown the index page in the pages folder but when I get to /index.php/about I still get the index.php file in the pages folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        //'index' => array('site/index'),
        '<view>' => array('site/page/view/'),
    ),
),
```

It should have been like this:

Comment: Yes, the rules cascade and the first matching rule is used. This means that if you have a rule matching on something as basic as "<view>" you will want to add it at the end of the rules list.

Answer (score 1):

Now the rule should be (at least in version 1.1.12)

```
'<view:\w+>' => 'site/page',
```

This code will provide $_GET['view'] to SiteController::actionPage, e.g. http://example.com/test will set $_GET['view'] = 'test'